# Why is Pandas data frame not fully pulling CSV info?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am pulling multiple excel files' information into a data frame using pandas in python.

Afterward, I am manipulating the information to produce a new result. This works just fine, but not on every CSV file.

Some files get returned with a missing column in the data frame, but the CSV file its self is completely intact.

I tried to copy all the info from one CSV to another, and that worked just fine, no missing content.

The issue is that the CSV file I am using is automatically produced, thus I have to be able to work with the original, not constantly make copies. P.S. I am converting the CSV to XLSX for required purposes.

Thanks in advance!

```
# Read CSV file found
csvFile = pd.read_csv(original_file)

# Rename new XL file to name of csv and save it
newFileName = f"{Path(original_file).stem}.xlsx"

resultExcelFile = pd.ExcelWriter(newFileName)

csvFile.to_excel(resultExcelFile, index=False)

resultExcelFile.save()

What it should be: 
DATE      TIME    FILE NAME
20230411  105927  123493
20230411  105927  456783
20230411  105927  895452
20230411  113527  126446
20230411  113527  464674

Current Issue:
DATE      TIME    FILE NAME
105927  123493
105927  456783
105927  895452
113527  126446
113527  464674
```

Comment: You would need to provide some sample of data that is not being import correctly. Otherwise it is only possible to guess ... generally for guessing I would suspect data abnormalities, blank lines, missing fields, bad syntax, improper formatting, ... and that is for starters.

Comment: Can you add some code here and outputs to help us understand better?

Comment: Content added!!

Comment: @mrawesome0238, can you share a reproducible example of one of the `.csv` as plain text (*comma-delimited*) with which you're having the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Until proven otherwise, passing `index_col=False` to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) should fix your problem.

> index_col: int, str, sequence of int / str, or False, optional, default
> None
> *> Column(s) to use as the row labels of the DataFrame, either given
> as string name or column index. If a sequence of int / str is given, a
> MultiIndex is used.*
>
> Note: `index_col=False` **can be used to force pandas to not use the first
> column as the index**, e.g. when you have **a malformed file** with
> delimiters at the end of each line.

```
csvFile = pd.read_csv(original_file, index_col=False) # <-- we add it here

newFileName = f"{Path(original_file).stem}.xlsx"

with pd.ExcelWriter(newFileName) as writer:
    csvFile.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Comment: That fixed the issue across the board, thank you so much!